# mysqldump + auto_increment causing primary key error

Tags: primary-key, mysql, auto-increment, duplicates

I am using mysqldump to (a) dump a table, then (b) insert it elsewhere.  A problem occurs when I try to do part (b).  Here is the error I get.

Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Now, hold on, hold on.  I know I'm not inserting duplicate primary keys .... I checked the CREATE TABLE statement.  The auto_incremement on the id field is left at the greatest value for the id column: AUTO_INCREMENT=45634650.  I believe that the problem is that MySQL will give this error if you try to insert any row with an id value less than what the auto_increment value is specified at .... regardless if that id is a duplicate or not.

I tried manually removing the AUTO_INCREMENT from the TABLE CREATE statement.  Same error still.

UPDATE:  Here are some relevant parts of the Create table statement.  Leaving out the inserts, even one of them is huge:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*Table structure for table `WC_ip` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `WC_ip`;

CREATE TABLE `WC_ip` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

etc etc .. =)

  `activity_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `userid_game_installAge` (`userid`,`game`,`install_age`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45750081 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

INSERT INTO `bi_user_daily` VALUES (1,1512489,'WC','1','GR','100001229652633','asfdasdf','http://www.facebook.com/asfdasdfasdffgdf','notif','gghgf','Secondary Paid Direct','2012-01-02',0,0,0.00,0,0,0,0,194,0,0,1325491229,'Google Chrome','16.0.912.63','windows','GR','178.146.208.153',0,1325491253,24,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'incomplete',91,2,1914,2,1,3.23,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,'2012-01-03','2012-01-03 07:06:57','2012-01-02'),

(2,1512490,'WC','1','TW','453','asdf','http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=blachdfhjdfkh','dfdsfg','','Primary Paid','2012-01-02',0,0,0.00,0,0,0,0,394,0,0,1325491233,'Google Chrome','16.0.912.63','windows','TW','114.41.159.234',0,1325491258,25,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'complete',120,2,2302,2,1,6.57,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,'2012-01-03','2012-01-03 07:06:57','2012-01-02'),

(3,1512491,'WC','1','','1590571243','','','notif','asfd','Secondary Paid Direct','2012-01-02',0,0,0.00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34535,'Mozilla Firefox','9.0.1','windows','-','10.54.48.31',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0.00,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,'2012-01-03','2012-01-03 07:06:57','2012-01-02')

CREATE TABLE `bi_user_daily` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.install_today` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.country` text,
  `main.fbid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.photo` text,
  `main.main.url` text,
  `main.fromstr` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.sourcestr` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.user_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.install_date_pst` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.install_hour_pst` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.revenue_primary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.revenue_secondary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.trans_primary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.trans_secondary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.direct_installs_generated` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.indirect_installs_generated` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.timeplayed_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.gift_sent_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main.monetized` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.usercreate_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.browser` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.browser_version` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.os` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.ip_address_country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.ip_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.noload` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.f.reate_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install.load_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.time_saved` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.playerLevel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.daysSinceInstall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.resource1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.resource2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.resource3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.resource4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.f.epairTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.dockRepairTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.fleetRepairTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.maxResearchTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.shipBuildTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.buildingUpgradeTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numf.Uncovered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.attackablef.Uncovered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numTerrainsUncovered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numFleets` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.battlesWon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.battlesTotal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numf.ttacks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numf.efends` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.totalResourcesCombat` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.totalResourcesProduced` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.bubbleTimeLeft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.FBCSpend` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numFriends` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numInstallsGenerated` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numGiftsRecd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numChatMessagesSent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numMissionsCompleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numAdvancedResearched` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numWeaponsResearched` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numArmorsResearched` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.f.numHullsResearched` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.summary.tutorial_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.summary.tutorial_stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.summary.user_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.summary.f.points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l.summary.f.loads` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key_metrics.logged_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key_metrics.timeplayed` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key_metrics.revenue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `virality.secondary_direct_install` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `virality.secondary_indirect_install` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monetization.secondary_direct_revenue` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monetization.secondary_indirect_revenue` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `install_age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_created_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_created_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userid_game_installAge` (`userid`,`game`,`install_age`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45634650 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is the ID field set to in the first 2 rows of the dump

Comment: Stupid question from me: Is the new table empty?

Comment: @Cassy should have been the first question I asked :-)

Comment: Yes, it does get created, with zero rows.

Comment: Add --skip-extended-insert to you dump might make it more readable

Comment: added, doesnt look too bad now

Comment: Getting there @user1082428 now can I be real lazy and ask for a mini dump that I can feed to mysql to create your condition :-) = (I noticed <cough> that "etc etc .. =)" isnt a good row. If I can replicate I may be able to answer your issue

Comment: @AdrianCornish it is in there now

Comment: Almost - will come back to this on the morrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this very same issue a few months ago (posted solution on my [blog](http://melikedev.com/2011/06/01/mysql-remove-auto_increment-from-schema-dumps-mysqldump/)). There is a [known issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786) with MySQL 5.1.11+ where if you do a mysqldump, it also outputs the auto_increment count (as you stated in your post). You can use `sed` (stream edit) and parse out the auto_increment construct when generating your dump file:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h <db-host> --opt <db-name> -d --single-transaction | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//' > <filename>.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the auto_increment values set as NULL or as a particular number if they are NULL they will use the next value as specified by the table definition. If they are explicitly expressed then they shall be inserted as that value unless a duplicate exists?

Comment: They are all set as numbers.  The table that all these values came from never had any problems with the id column, and I never did any manipulation of them either

Comment: @user1082428 can you post the "relevant" parts of the create table and the first couple of insert values statements. Oh and like Cassy said - is the table empty?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you

```
ALTER TABLE table2 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

or remove primary key on table2 and find same records.

Comment: I dont think that will help because if the id is explicit in the dump then resetting the auto_increment on the table will cause problems later